# RecyclerView.ViewHolder goes null outside onBindViewHolder method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am creating a custom adapter where i am using two view holders, if the list is at position 0 holder object is casted to first view holder otherwise to second. the issue is when i am using that first view holder object outside onBindViewHolder it throws null pointer exception. here is my code

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        firstholder = (FirstHolder) holder;
   } else {
        secondholder = (SecondHolder) holder;
    }
}
    public void runnable(final int size) {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        if (firstholder.ViewPager.getCurrentItem() == size - 1) {
                    firstholder.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(0); 
           } else {
                    firstholder.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(firstholder.ViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);                }
                handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable);
                handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 1000);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

its throwing exception when called in runnable.
Note that: both viewholder objects are global

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? which line is throwing NullPointer? Also post the code for the remainder of the adapter, specifically `onCreateViewHolder` and `getItemViewType` methods

Comment: in run method where i am calling viewpager through firstholder

Comment: "Runnable = new Runnable()"? , you should have some variable "Runnable runs=new Runnable()"

Comment: I think he means here: firstholder.ViewPager.getCurrentItem()

Comment: yes @Leonardo 
and btw she not he :P

Comment: The syntax is wrong leonardo Runnable = new Runnable??

Comment: sorry haha, so, post your stacktrace

Comment: oh while posting i wrote this by mistake.. runnable is a variable already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this

```
final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

if (itemType == 0) {
firstholder = (FirstHolder) holder;
}else {
secondholder = (SecondHolder) holder;
}
```